# Nokia Maps: retrieve speed limit based on coordinates using REST API

Tags: rest, here-api

I am sure it's possible to retrieve speed limit on the road based on coordinates. I just can't find any example (rest API). As I understand I need to use routing mechanism to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to use the `getLinkInfo` endpoint from the [Enterprise Routing API.](http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-routing). The `speedLimit` element returned is in **m/s** so multiply by 3.6 for **km/h** or 2.23 for **mph**. If the `speedLimit` element is missing then the national speed limit applies.

[http://route.st.nlp.nokia.com/routing/6.2/getlinkinfo.json?waypoint=52.5308,13.3846&app_id=**your_app_id**&app_code=**your_app_code**](http://route.st.nlp.nokia.com/routing/6.2/getlinkinfo.json?waypoint=52.5308,13.3846&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg)

A working example can be found on the [HERE Maps Community Examples](http://heremaps.github.io/examples/explorer.html#speed-limit-on-click__index) on GitHub

Answer (score 7):

**UDPATE: For others that see this question now:**

The answer above doesn't work anymore (it doesn't return anything) - you need to use API 7.2 now:

[http://route.st.nlp.nokia.com/routing/**7.2**/getlinkinfo.json?waypoint=52.5308,13.3846&app_id=**your_app_id**&app_code=**your_app_code**](http://route.st.nlp.nokia.com/routing/7.2/getlinkinfo.json?waypoint=52.5308,13.3846&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg)

Maybe that helps someone!

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**

`getlinkinfo` will depreciated 31.03.2017. You will have to use Platform Data Extension.

[HERE Speed Limit via PDE Demo](https://github.com/seaBass3/here-pde-speed-limit/blob/master/Here_PDE_Demo.php)

### --------------

**UPDATE - 2**

I've got an email from HERE:

> In December 2016, we informed our customers that we will retire the getlinkinfo (beta) functionality of the HLP Router API 7.2 by March 31, 2017 and that we would like to ask you to migrate to the Platform Data Extension by this date.
>
> Based on the feedback that we received from several customers **we decided to extend the time** for migration and **keep getlinkinfo available** until **June 30, 2017** and informed our customers accordingly.

Comment: Now getting the speed limit is harder than it used to be. Code you provided does not work for coordinates: lat = 51.089148 and lng = 17.0119348. I don't know why...

Comment: I checked old REST API and its works very well. I don't know how long, but it works. I've made a simple JS script to get speed limit from HERE into my car, see: [artemis.wszib.edu.pl/~msokol/test.html](https://artemis.wszib.edu.pl/~msokol/test.html) (on mobile phone or other small screen device :)

Answer (score 3):

At the moment this gives you the speed limit from HERE:

[https://route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=52.5308,13.3846&waypoint1=52.5308,13.3846&legattributes=**li**&mode=fastest;car&app_code=**your_app_code**&app_id=**your_app_id**](https://route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=52.5308,13.3846&waypoint1=52.5308,13.3846&legattributes=li&mode=fastest;car&app_code=your_app_code&app_id=your_app_id)

To get the speed limit you need to pass the argument `legattributes=li`. The `speedLimit` element is still returned in m/s so multiply by 3.6 for km/h or 2.23 for mph as Jason Fox mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** Since Nokia maps renamed to **HERE maps**, its good practice to use their new **HERE API**.

Check their [documentation](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/routing/link-information-for-a-location) how to use it with GPS coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the HERE ReverseGeocoder with parameter "locationattributes=linkInfo" to get the speed and some more usefull information. Example response:

```
  linkInfo: {
     functionalClass: 5,
     travelDirection: [
        "NE"
     ],
     speedCategory: "SC7",
     speedLimit: [
        {
           value: 30,
           unit: "kph"
        }
     ],
     linkFlags: [
        "Paved"
     ],
     accessFlags: [
        "Automobiles",
        "Motorcycles",
        "Buses",
        "Taxis",
        "Carpools",
        "Pedestrians",
        "Trucks",
        "Deliveries",
        "EmergencyVehicle",
        "ThroughTraffic"
     ]
  }
```

See the full details at https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/topics/resource-reverse-geocode.html

Answer (score 1):

**

> **Version 8.3 Here map 2020**

**

For Getting Speed Limit you must pass 2 value

spans=speedLimit

return=polyline

```
https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?apiKey=APP_KEY&transportMode=car&origin=-37.956650,145.220673&destination=-37.956650,145.220673&spans=speedLimit&return=polyline
```

in result you will get this:

```
                "polyline": "BG1j2soC6iy_0IAA",
                "spans": [
                    {
                        "offset": 0,
                        "speedLimit": 100.0
                    }
                ],
```

for more information please check this link:

[Here Map V.8.3.1](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/8.3.1/api-reference-swagger.html)

Answer (score 0):

> getlinkinfo will depreciated 31.03.2017. You will have to use Platform Data Extension.

I found what you were looking for:

https://route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/getlinkinfo.json?app_id=APP_ID&app_code=APP_CODE&mode=car&waypoint=-37.732895,144.853912&linkattributes=all

Hope this help.

Comment: I tried your URL . But it gives the following response .{"response":{"_type":"ns2:RoutingServiceErrorType","type":"SystemError","subtype":"SystemError","details":"These credentials do not authorize access. Please contact your customer representative or submit a request here https://developer.here.com/contact-us to upgrade your account. You can also get valid credentials by registering for a free trial license on https://developer.here.com.","metaInfo":{"timestamp":"2018-05-15T13:04:58Z","mapVersion":"8.30.83.151","moduleVersion":"7.2.201818-21651","interfaceVersion":"2.6.34"}}}