# Google Map Maker - Speed limit

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, appcelerator-mobile

I would like to get the speed limit from different road using Google Map Maker (or another solution) to create an application (with appcelerator to be able to use it on iOS and Android) that warn me when I drive over the speed limit of the actual road (using GPS).

Very Cordially.

Comment: google does not provide speed limit data of streets

Comment: Google provides it, not directly, but through Google Map Maker and all his users and verifications. If this database exists, there would be a mean to be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

To get the speed limit data you can use nokia Here maps or Google.

For nokia Here refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21883255/nokia-maps-retrieve-speed-limit-based-on-coordinates-using-rest-api) and examples [here](http://heremaps.github.io/examples/explorer.html#speed-limit-on-click__index)

Google has started providing optional speed limit data.
See Roads Web Service section at following link. https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing